# Avalonia - using the in-built Avalonia.Data.Converters

Tags: xaml, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am trying to use the `BoolConverters.And` converter, but cannot seem to find a way to get it working inside XAML.

**Xmlns declaration:**

```
xmlns:acon="clr-namespace:Avalonia.Data.Converters.BoolConverters;assembly=Avalonia.Base"
```

**Resources:**

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <acon:And x:Key="andConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

**The binding:** (I hope I got the multi-value syntax right)

```
<StackPanel.IsVisible>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{DynamicResource andConverter}">
        <MultiBinding.Bindings>
            <Binding Path="Foo"/>
            <Binding Path="Bar"/>
        </MultiBinding.Bindings>
    </MultiBinding>
</StackPanel.IsVisible>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Converter="{x:Static BoolConverters.And}"`. see 
https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/blob/cc714a203c3a16310bd4104a38f8a525588f65a2/src/Avalonia.Themes.Default/TextBox.xaml#L25 for usage example.

Comment: For the list of built-in converters see http://avaloniaui.net/docs/binding/converting-binding-values#built-in-converters